# Setting state based on API response

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm setting a Widget state based on the result of an API call, like so:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
      future: Api().getItems(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          setState(() {
            items = snapshot.data['items']
              .map((item) => Item.fromJson(item))
              .toList();
          });

          // Do things with items..
        }
      }
  );
}
```

This code fails with a `setState() or markNeedsBuild called during build` error. I'm wondering what the correct approach to doing this would be?

I've tried removing items from my state and just accessing `snapshot.data['items']` directly but this has the undesirable side-effect of hot-reload no longer working.

Comment: why you use setState inside build? 
setState it call build function again , its not healthy, you have to use  setState when you want to refresh the page

Comment: @MahmoudSabri where should the API call go instead?

Comment: you can call it inside initState()

Comment: In that case, do I track the error/loading states via private instance variables (e.g. `is_loading`, `is_error`) for updating the UI?